# Conditional RgEx with PHP preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex

Just have to select Conditional Regex.

Here is what i have problem....

I just want to select time string 02:00 but not with quotation marks like "02:00" or '02:00'

I am using to select 02:00 or 2:00 Regex is

```
$pattern = '/(\d{2}:\d{2})|(\d{1}:\d{2})/';
preg_match_all($pattern,$content, $matches);
```

But is selecting this also "02:00" or '02:00' I am not sure which regex will use to skip that time string.

I got this http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html But not sure how make regex :(

Please help me out.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for Lucas Trzesniewski and his Great Help.

I just resolved my issue with this php code.

```
 $pattern = '/(?!["\'])\b\d{1,2}:\d{2}\b(?!["\'])/';
  preg_match_all($pattern,$content, $matches);
```

Comment: add your content too, which you are trying to match with preg_match_all, means the string too...

Comment: Thanks Ameenullah, I just resolved my issue with this regex, (?!["'])\b\d{1,2}:\d{2}\b(?!["'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditionals won't help you much in this case.

The simplest way is to use lookarounds:

```
(?<!["'])\b\d{1,2}:\d{2}\b(?!["'])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vS2sT9/2)

- `(?<!["'])` (negative lookbehind) will make sure the preceding character is not single or double quote
- `(?!["'])` (negative lookahead) will do the same for the following character

Comment: Or even `(?<!["'\d])\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?![\d"'])`, just in case there are `000022302:00030455`-like strings.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you're right, thanks. I added word boundaries

Comment: Thanks for this Great Help

Comment: What if i want to include to select timestamp with this 00:00:00 and should not select with "00:00:00"  I just have this one (?!["'])\b\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?\b(?!["']) but its selecting time with "00:00:00"