# Change timestamp into shortcode using php and regex

Tags: php, regex

Here is content.

2:00

10:00

03:00

1:04:01

01:04:01

So Above timestamp should change into shortcode for example

[spp-timestamp time="(timestamp)"]

But should not touch existing shortcodes

Like Below

[spp-timestamp time="1:05:01"]

[spp-timestamp time="01:05:01"]

[spp-timestamp time="4:00"]

[spp-timestamp time="15:00"]

[spp-timestamp time="05:00"]

Here is what i am using php and regex.

```
$pattern= '/(?!["\'])\b\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?\b(?!["\'])/';
           preg_match_all($pattern,$content, $matches); 
                foreach ($matches[0] as $time){     
                         $shortcode = '[spp-timestamp time="'.$time. '"]';
                         $content = str_replace($time, $shortcode, $content);
                }

         }
```

Here is what i am getting results.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2:00 [1] => 10:00 [2] => 03:00 [3] => 1:04:01 [4] => 01:04:01 [5] => 1:05 [6] => 01:05 ) ) 
    [spp-timestamp time="2:00"]

    [spp-timestamp time="10:00"]

    [spp-timestamp time="03:00"]

    [spp-timestamp time="1:04:01"]

    0[spp-timestamp time="1:04:01"]



    Shortcode:
    [spp-timestamp time="[spp-timestamp time="1:05"]:01"]
    [spp-timestamp time="0[spp-timestamp time="1:05"]:01"] 
    [spp-timestamp time="4:00"] 
    [spp-timestamp time="15:00"] 
    [spp-timestamp time="05:00"]
```

Not sure why its selecting time from shortcode :(

Also this one timestamp 01:04:01 generating this shortocde means ZERO is skipped.

0[spp-timestamp time="1:04:01"]

**UPDATE**

I think i got it why its selecting time from shortcode.

There is problem with regex

```
(?!["'])\b\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\b(?!["'])
```

I don't have much experience in regex.

Above is for selecting timestamp without quotation mart but its working with just MM:SS not with HH:MM:SS

For example "2:00" but its not working with "00:00:00"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the replace function. When you reach index 4 (1:04:01), you are replacing '1:04:01' in your original string. It is replaing '01:04:01' as well and 0 is kept out.

Your question doesn't explained why do you need to perform replace with str_replace. You can use replace method in regular expression itself.

Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to find and replace.

I am not sure about the input but assuming it is text. So below is your code

```
$text = "2:00 10:00 3:00  1:04:01 01:04:01";

$replacement = 'spp-timestamp time="${1}"';
$matches = preg_filter ('/(?!["\'])\b(\d{1,2}:\d{2})(?::\d{2})?\b(?!["\'])/',$replacement, $text);

print_r($matches);
```

Below is the output:

```
string 'spp-timestamp time="2:00" spp-timestamp time="10:00" spp-timestamp time="3:00"  spp-timestamp time="1:04" spp-timestamp time="01:04"' (length=132)
```

Let me know if this is what you expected.

Comment: How can i replace with regular expression ? Can you please increase my knowledge :)

Comment: Okay but not sure actually not have very much experience in that. can you please right exact code. What should i do ?

Comment: I can help you out, but can you put your current code. I mean Input and expected output (array, list, string)?

Comment: Also i did not able to understand why its selecting time from shortcode     [spp-timestamp time="[spp-timestamp time="1:05"]:01"] May be problem in regex ??

Comment: Here is output with print_r Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2:00 [1] => 10:00 [2] => 03:00 [3] => 1:04:01 [4] => 01:04:01 [5] => 1:05 [6] => 01:05 ) )

Comment: Thanks for the code its better what i was have. But Problem with regex still there See there i have already posted question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272935/conditional-rgex-with-php-preg-match-all

Comment: Can we skype at umershaikh79